# rails: mass-assignment security concern with belongs_to relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, mass-assignment

I've been reading up on rails security concerns and the one that makes me the most concerned is mass assignment.  My application is making use of attr_accessible, however I'm not sure if I quite know what the best way to handle the exposed relationships is.  Let's assume that we have a basic content creation/ownership website.  A user can have create blog posts, and have one category associated with that blog post.

So I have three models:

- **user**
- **post:** belongs to a user and a category
- **category:** belongs to user

I allow mass-assignment on the category_id, so the user could nil it out, change it to one of their categories, or through mass-assignment, I suppose they could change it to someone else's category.  That is where I'm kind of unsure about what the best way to proceed would be.

The resources I have investigated (particularly [railscast #178](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/178-seven-security-tips) and a [resource](http://railspikes.com/2008/9/22/is-your-rails-application-safe-from-mass-assignment) that was provided from that railscast), both mention that the association should not be mass-assignable, which makes sense.  I'm just not sure how else to allow the user to change what the **category** of the **post** would be in a railsy way.

Any ideas on how best to solve this?  Am I looking at it the wrong way?

**UPDATE**: Hopefully clarifying my concern a bit more.

Let's say I'm in Post, do I need something like the following:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:category])

  @post.user_id = current_user.id

  # CHECK HERE IF REQUESTED CATEGORY_ID IS OWNED BY USER

  # continue on as normal here
end
```

That seems like a lot of work?  I would need to check that on every controller in both the update and create action.  Keep in mind that there is more than just one belongs_to relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so searched around a bit, and finally came up with something workable for me.  I like keeping logic  out of the controllers where possible, so this solution is a model-based solution:

```
# Post.rb
validates_each :asset_category_id do |record, attr, value|
  self.validates_associated_permission(record, attr, value)
end

# This can obviously be put in a base class/utility class of some sort.
def self.validates_associated_permission(record, attr, value)
  return if value.blank?
  class_string = attr.to_s.gsub(/_id$/, '')
  klass = class_string.camelize.constantize

  # Check here that the associated record is the users
  # I'm leaving this part as pseudo code as everyone's auth code is
  # unique.
  if klass.find_by_id(value).can_write(current_user)
    record.errors.add attr, 'cannot be found.'
  end
end
```

I also found that rails 3.0 will have a better way to specify this instead of the 3 lines required for the ultra generic validates_each.

http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/8/11/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-independent-model-validators

Comment: Other answer was very helpful, but this is what actually solved my problem, thus I'm accepting it.

Answer (score 5):

Your user can change it through an edit form of some kind, i presume.

Based on that, Mass Assignment is really for nefarious types who seek to mess with your app through things like curl.  I call them curl kiddies.

All that to say, if you use `attr_protected` - (here you put the fields you Do Not want them to change) or the kid's favourite `attr_accessible`(the fields that are OK to change).

You'll hear arguments for both, but if you use `attr_protected :user_id` in your model, and then in your CategoryController#create action you can do something like

```
def create
  @category = Category.new(params[:category])

  @category.user_id = current_user.id
  respond_to do |format|
....#continue on as normal here
end
```

Comment: Thanks @pjammer.  I'm particularly interested in the example above.  What you have written is correct, but I'm more interested in the belongs_to from Post to Category.  I already have something like this (though I have it in the model) for the current_user on Post and Category.